# New Instance of Controller Created on $state.go() angular-ui-router

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, angular-ui-router

I'm having some trouble understanding how routing works with angular-ui-router and states.

I have an app built on ionic (v1), angular, and esri jsapi. I'm using ionic side menu and angular-ui-router. On loading my site, you get the map view, when using the side menu to navigate to a station, then viewing the details of a station, then clicking on the map button to zoom to the location on the map, I do a $state.go() to the map view, and you'll see that the view/controller is initialized again. You can see this by reviewing the console and seeing "CREATE MAP" displayed again, after the initial load of the map view.

I've setup my states like so:

```
        .state('app.map', {
            url: '/map',
            cache: true,
            reload: false,
            params: {
                attributes: null
            },
            views: {
                'menuContent': {
                    templateUrl: 'templates/map.html',
                    controller: 'MapController'
                }
            }
        })
        .state('app.detail', {
            url: '/detail',
            cache: false,
            params: {
                properties: null
            },
            views: {
                'menuContent': {
                    templateUrl: 'templates/detail.html',
                    controller: 'DetailController'
                }
            }
        })
```

I would like to avoid having the map view/controller re-instantiated when transitioning from the detail view to the map view. I expect the button click from the detail page to transition to the original map view state, but I suspect it's trying to create another instance of the map view. If I click on the side menu button for map, it doesn't re-initialize and I get the original map view.

Site here:

[EV Charge Stations](https://toidp.com/EVChargeStations/www/#/app/map)

Comment: I have the same problem over here... Any thoughts on how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try going through these discussion may be it can help you
https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/issues/1758, https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/issues/64

Also since it is working fine if you use ng-href like in the side menu map option so instead of using ng-click use ui-href and call your function that return the state name. Something like this;

```
    <ion-item ng-repeat="feature in features | filter: {attributes: {Property: search.input}} as filteredCount" 
class="item item-icon-left item-icon-right"
 ui-sref={{onListItemClick({&quot;Station_Id&quot;:487,&quot;Property&quot;:&quot;Neal Blaisdell Center Parking Structure&quot;,&quot;Street_Address&quot;:&quot;777 Ward Avenue&quot;,&quot;City&quot;:&quot;Honolulu&quot;,&quot;Zip_Code&quot;:96814,&quot;Island&quot;:&quot;Oahu&quot;,&quot;In_Use&quot;:&quot;No&quot;,&quot;Charger_Fee_Type&quot;:&quot;Free&quot;,&quot;Charger_Notes&quot;:&quot;Enter S. King Street/Victoria street.  Follow blue signs to Charger.&quot;,&quot;Hours_of_Operation&quot;:&quot;6:00am-12:00am&quot;,&quot;Charger_Count&quot;:1,&quot;Charger_Port&quot;:1,&quot;Charger_Level&quot;:2,&quot;Charger_Fee&quot;:&quot;Free&quot;,&quot;Parking_Fee&quot;:&quot;Free for EV Drivers&quot;,&quot;Network&quot;:&quot;ChargePoint&quot;,&quot;Notes&quot;:&quot;Activate charger with ChargePoint Network card or call the number listed on the front of the charger for access. &quot;,&quot;Latitude&quot;:21.299434,&quot;Longitude&quot;:-157.850378,&quot;Location&quot;:&quot;(21.299434, -157.850378)&quot;,&quot;Other1&quot;:null,&quot;Other2&quot;:null,&quot;Other3&quot;:null,&quot;Other4&quot;:null,&quot;Other5&quot;:null,&quot;Other6&quot;:null,&quot;Other7&quot;:null,&quot;Other8&quot;:null,&quot;Other9&quot;:null,&quot;Other10&quot;:null,&quot;FID&quot;:3,&quot;CreationDate&quot;:1484871379520,&quot;Creator&quot;:&quot;dpascual_HEC&quot;,&quot;EditDate&quot;:1484871379520,&quot;Editor&quot;:&quot;dpascual_HEC&quot;,&quot;Hawaiian_Station&quot;:null,&quot;OwnedBy&quot;:null,&quot;ChargingStandards&quot;:null,&quot;Servicing&quot;:null,&quot;ServiceNotes&quot;:null}) }}>

                </ion-item>
```

Controller.js

```
$scope.onListItemClick = function (attributes) {
            var data = {
                properties: attributes
            };
            return "app.detail({attributes:"+data+"})" ;
        }
```

I hope this solves your problem.